# How can I send and receive Whatsapp messages?

Tags: c#, python, message, whatsapp

How can I send messages to other Whatsapp users? And when it is possible how can i receive messages?
I know this C# library for it but I don t have a password and you need it to log in or sth line that. And this Whatsapp Wart isn t working too. Is there an option to receive a password with c# or python?
And please don t link other questions about this, because these technics aren t working.

Thank you.

Comment: Firstly, you mention a specific library, what is its name (the one you have no password for). Secondly, it is generally good practice to include details of what you have tried, i.e. What is not working about the framework. 

If you can clarify these details it would help quite a bit.

Comment: I just want to know a way which is working. There is only one big library for these things. But you need a password to "log into your account" there for yo have to request one . There are some Warts to do that in the internet and some software but nothing of these are working so im asking where can i get this password for my whatsapp account because normally you haven t one

Comment: The only framework I've found in a search or two is https://github.com/danielcardeenas/whatsapp-framework which uses Python. There seem to be a couple of examples in the questions section there which might help to. 

The only framework I've found in a search or two is https://github.com/danielcardeenas/whatsapp-framework which uses Python. There seem to be a couple of examples in the questions section there which might help to.

Comment: As for a password the method for getting one relies on you already having a mobile phone with WhatsApp on. The method to do so can be found here though I haven't tested it: https://github.com/danielcardeenas/whatsapp-framework/blob/master/README.md